# Algorithm for finding thickest line?

Tags: algorithm

I'm sorry if topic is confusing. It's because I don't know what i'm really searching for. I have a set P of points (`|P| < 10^5`). Each point have integer coordinates (`between -10^4, 10^4`) How to find straight, which goes across all of points specified on input. Condition is that line must be the thickest, and you have to output how thick that straight is with accuracy up to 2 places after decimal point. Any hint, clue, idea or algorithm name would be appreciate.

PS. It's neither homework nor SPOJ. I'm just preparing to programming contest by doing problems from last edition. And that one I can't solve, even I don't know where to start for searching solution...

Comment: I don't know the exactly answer but can give some interesting ideas to you. Actually you should find the equation of two parallel thinnest lines (thick=1) that all the point is placed between them. The answer of the problem is the distance of these two lines.

Comment: By the way, aren't you trying to find the *thinnest* line that is thick enough to enclose all points in P?

Comment: Agreed with Astrotrain. Finding 'thick' line doesn't make sense to me. You should elaborate more. You know what let's draw a line with infinite thickness, now that's the thickest line that goes across the input.

Comment: Yes I meant thinest line, otherwise it would be pointless. Sorry for my bad english :S

Answer (score 1):

You could start by determining the convex hull of this point cloud (see e.g. http://softsurfer.com/Archive/algorithm_0109/algorithm_0109.htm), and try to find the two parallel lines that bound this polygon with the shortest distance.

I think this should be an easier problem because it allows you to base the direction of the parallel lines on the segments of the convex hull (of which there are a limited number).

One implementation could be to process each segment of the convex hull in turn. Per segment, draw a line through it (this is one of the two parallel lines), and then determine the closest other parallel line that encloses the convex hull. Do this for each segment of the convex hull while recording the minimum distance you have found between the parallel lines so far. At the end you should have your optimum result.

Obviously, this still requires an efficient way to determine the closest other parallel line. A (naive, but maybe good enough) way of doing this, is to take all vertices of the convex hull that are not on the current segment, and determine the perpendicular distance to the line through it (e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_from_a_point_to_a_line). The maximum distance for all these vertices is also the minimum distance to the parallel line.

In pseudo-code:

```
Function FindThinnestLine(PointCloud P)
   CH = ConvexHull(P)

   optS = nothing
   optDist = infinite

   For each segment S in CH
      L = the line through S

      /* Find the minimum distance that the line parallel to L must have in order to enclose CH */
      maxDist = 0
      For each vertex P in CH, except the two that limit S
         dist = The distance between L and P
         maxDist = max(dist, maxDist)

      /* If the current S has a smaller maxDist, it is our new optimum */
      if(maxDist < optDist)
         optS = S
         optDist = maxDist

   Return the line through optS and the line parallel to optS at a distance of optDist as the result
End Function
```

This is an O(n^2) algorithm, with n being the number of segments in your convex hull.

**Edit**
Come to think of it, you don't need to iterate over O(n) vertices of the convex hull for every S (in order to find the maxDist), only for the *first* S. Let's say we call this first vertex oppV (*opp* for opposite to S), and let's say we process the segments of the convex hull in clockwise order. For every subsequent S that we process, the new oppV can be either the same vertex, or one of its right neigbours (but never a left neighbour, otherwise the segments wouldn't form a convex polygon).
Hence, processing the segments of the convex hull can then be done in O(n) (but creating the convex hull is still O(n log n)).

Comment: Why one of those lines must lie on a segment? I can think of that it's not neccesarly true: http://i50.tinypic.com/jzu24x.jpg

Comment: Ok, but your example is not optimal, the two red lines could be closer:
In your example, rotate the two parallel lines counterclockwise, so that the left line coincides
with the bottom left segment of the polygon. You will find that the polygon is still enclosed
by the two red lines and that there is now some extra space* between the polygon and the right red
line. Hence, the right red line can now be moved closer to the left line.

Comment: * If you find it hard to see this, realise that the center segment of the polygon is  
perpendicular to the red lines in your example and therefore represents the maximum distance between
the red lines. When you rotate the center segment (but keep the same length) a bit, you will find
that it no longer touches the other red line: the required distance between the red lines has
now become smaller.

Answer (score 0):

The thickest line containing all points of a given subset of P should be the perpendicular bisector of the segment `xy`, where `x` and `y` are those two points of the subset with the `highest distance d` between them. The thickness of this line would be `d` as well.